# where can I get all names of connections in the graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

```
import facebook

token = 'your token'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

the second parameter in the method get_connections() is the name if a connection, I found the documentation of graph api (http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) but I could not get the information how I get a list with all names of all connections which exist in a graph.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use the official API reference, all the existing connections are in there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference

For example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

(Scroll down to "Edges")

Comment: I just begun today to test the python graph API (I am very new there, also in python :) )

what would you recommend to read in order to understand the background of all technique? 

thanks!

Comment: well, i would not use python ;) - i would start reading the docs from the beginning and especially try to get used to the javascript sdk. because that is the easiest one. here´s an article i wrote about it a while ago: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/